# Javascript/jQuery to bookmark a webpage in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarks

I have a code that bookmarks a link successfully in IE, FF and Opera; however the same script doesn't work in Chrome and Safari. I researched a lot, didn't find anything worthy, it will be really helpful if anyone shares how to get this implemented successfully in Chrome and Safari browsers. Please find below the JavaScript function that I have used.

```
     <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
     function CreateBookmarkLink() {
     chkpar = "<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>";

     var title="";

     if(chkpar=="" || chkpar=="/index_sub.php" || chkpar=="/index.php")
        {
                title="My Home Page";
        }

     url = "http://www.mysite.com<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>";

            if (window.sidebar) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
                    window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url,"");
            } else if(window.external) { // IE Favorite
                    window.external.AddFavorite( url, title); }
            else if(window.opera && window.print) { // Opera Hotlist
                    return true; }
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: I think you will better be helped when you tell the problem you have. Error messages, wrong behaviour, etc. What is it?

Comment: When I try to bookmark a link through this script in chrome, it throws an error - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'AddFavorite'

For sure, chrome doesn't support this. My point of interest here is to find out - how we can achieve to bookmark a link in chrome through a javascript or jquery code?

Thanks,
Diwakar

Comment: Can't do that in Chrome, using JS

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457572/how-to-add-to-favorites-bookmark-for-all-browser-in-javascript