# How to add to Favorites/Bookmark for all browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarks

I have some query in Add to favorites/Bookmarked web page using java script.I just go through in this [Link](http://www.apphp.com/index.php?snippet=javascript-add-to-favorites-button) and get this source code. It's been working perfectly for the last month. Yet now it will not work in any browser. Here is my code :

```
function CreateBookmarkLink(){
        var title = document.title;
        var url = document.location.href;

        if(window.sidebar){
            /* Mozilla Firefox Bookmark */
            window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, "");
        }else if(window.external){
            /* IE Favorite */
            window.external.AddFavorite(url, title);
        }else if(window.opera && window.print) {
            /* Opera Hotlist */
            alert("Press Control + D to bookmark");
            return true;
        }else{
            /* Other */
            alert("Press Control + D to bookmark");
        }
 <a href="javascript:CreateBookmarkLink();">Add to Favorites/Bookmark</a>
```

It doesn't work in any browser any more and just displays:

> TypeError: window.sidebar.addPanel is not a function
>   **> window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, "");**

Any ideas how to solve it? I also need to add favorites in chrome browser. Any other idea to create bookmark for my website.

Comment: Your function is missing a semicolon

Answer (score 7):

Due to security reasons it is not possible to add a bookmark in Google Chrome using Javascript.

Alternatively, you could output a message for using the shortcut:

```
    $('#bookmarkme').click(function(){
        alert('Press ' + (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') != - 1 ? 'Command/Cmd' : 'CTRL') + ' + D to bookmark this page.');
    });
```

Since `window.sidebar.addPanel` is deprecated and not a standard implementation  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/APIWwindow.sidebar), you may use the API to add bookmarks when creating an add-on (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Bookmarks).

Nevertheless it should not be a high burden for users to add their favorite website as bookmark inside the browser.